# Assumed size arrays in fortran

Tags: arrays, fortran

I wrote the following program to mess around with assumed-shape and assumed-size arrays:

```
program test

implicit none

    integer, dimension(3) :: array

    array(1) = 1
    array(2) = 2
    array(3) = 3

    call mysub(array)

end program test

subroutine mysub(array)

    dimension array(*)

    print *, array(:3)

end subroutine mysub
```

I'm compiling it with `ifort` and have 2 questions:

- The subroutine outputs random values not equal to the values I assign in the main program. Why is this?
- if I replace line 19 `print *, array(:3)` by `print *, ubound(array)` I get an error message

> test.f90(19): error #6587: Upper Bound of array is not computable.
>   [UBOUND]

I do want to be able to detect the upper bound of my assumed-size array within the subroutine. How can I do this?

Comment: If you would follow the ubiquitous advice about implicit none you would likely solve this yourself.  Your subroutine expects real data type.   No doubt the question has many duplicates

Comment: As you have two questions, we can't easily point you to another useful question.  However, as using `implicit none` (as noted by tim18) makes the answer to the first trivial, I'll propose that the second question is a duplicate of another.  Things are slightly different, but the whole issue is that assumed-size arrays don't have upper bounds.